# How do I use a newer version of jQuery with Ubercart shipping quote (Ajax)?

Tags: ajax, javascript, ubercart

If I use any version of jQuery with drupal/ubercart other than jquery 1.2.6, the ajax comes back from (UPS,Fedex,etc), but never updates the objects on the screen.

How do I use a more current version of jQuery with ubercart?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, Ubercart will NOT work with jQuery after 1.2.6 unless you make a small change to an Ubercart module

ubercart/shipping/uc_quote/uc_quote.pages.inc

Go to around line 70 which should be the end of the uc_quote_request_quotes function

comment out or replace the broken drupal_json($return_quotes);

replace it with the standard PHP json encoder
print( json_encode($return_quotes) );

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to update jQuery on Drupal is with the [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module:

> Upgrades the version of jQuery in Drupal core to a newer version of jQuery.
>
> Updates...
>
> - Drupal 5 to jQuery 1.2.6
> - Drupal 6 to jQuery 1.3.2
> - Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.11

I've got a few old sites using Drupal 6 + Ubercart that work fine with the jQuery update module installed.

Comment: I'm running Drupal 6.  I've ran jquery update.  Only when I use jquery update does it not work

Comment: I think you've got something else interfering then, as I say I've got several sites that use Ubercart and the AJAX works perfectly in the checkout screen. Checking the JS console for errors would be a good place to start

Comment: checked console with firebug.  There aren't any errors.  ajax call comes back perfectly as well.  If you add this product, you can see it won't work using jquery 1.4.2  http://www.proloanmods.com/product/red-line-oil-synthetic-racing-oil-quarts